# Optimized search in pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have the following database:

```
{'docdb': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 9, 5: 14, 6: 18},
'cited_docdb': {0: [4],
 1: [0, 0, 0],
 2: [],
 3: [2],
 4: [4],
 5: [18, 6],
 6: [7]},
'fronteer': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 9.0, 3: nan, 4: 7.0, 5: 3.0, 6: 1.0},
'distance': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 0.0, 3: nan, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0}}
```

and would basically like to do the following in an optimized way: whenever at least a 0 occurs in the list cited_docdb and the distance variable is NaN substitute the distance with a 1.
Now there is a naive way to do it which is the following:

```
m1= [0 in x for x in df['cited_docdb']]
df.loc[m1&df['distance'].isna(), 'distance'] = 1
```

which is great for small databases but it's very slow when the database has millions of observations and if I have this operation iteratively. In particular, this is because at every iteration m1 will check all the values of df['cited_docdb'] whereas it only needed to look at the values where distance is NaN (i.e. something along the lines of `m1_new = [0 in x for x in df.loc[df['distance'].isna(), 'cited_docdb']]`). So my question is: is there a way to basically combine this instruction `m1_new = [0 in x for x in df.loc[df['distance'].isna(), 'cited_docdb']]` with this `df['distance'].isna()` and assign a 1 whenever the 2 of them are satisfied? If not, is there another faster way to obtain the desired result shown below (again this is a mock example: in reality consider that the db has millions of observations and that the above operation must be executed 10000 times)?

```
{'docdb': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 9, 5: 14, 6: 18},
 'cited_docdb': {0: [4],
  1: [0, 0, 0],
  2: [],
  3: [2],
  4: [4],
  5: [18, 6],
  6: [7]},
 'fronteer': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 9.0, 3: nan, 4: 7.0, 5: 3.0, 6: 1.0},
 'distance': {0: nan, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: nan, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0}}
```

Thank you

Comment: the result looks same as source - what am I missing here?

Comment: If you notice there is a distance =1 rathe than a nan in the second position

Answer (score 0):

in this specific case you can use the fact that 0 is the smallest number (after abs() and fillna(1)), and calculate m1 without a loop:

```
m1 = (pd.DataFrame(list(df['cited_docdb'].values)).abs().fillna(1).min(axis=1)==0).values
```